# Online MS Access SQL script testing

Tags: ms-access

Is there some online tool available similar to [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) but for MS Access? I've spent some minutes searching and I can't find any.

Comment: There is some discussion of this matter here: http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com/q/778/5074 in the comments

Comment: Thanks, I would cast my vote for MS-Access but I see is somewhat difficult as it does not have ease JDBC access